# Can't bind JSON results to Component variable

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm trying a simple component that has to pull data from a JSON file. I'm almost copying the functionality from generated Fountain App, but for some reason I can't get the desired results. I have a component like:

```
import {Component, Inject} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'body-selector',
  template: require('./body.html')
})

@Inject(Http)

export class BodyComponent {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.getText('app/texts/main.json').subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    this.texts = result;
  });
  console.log(this.texts);
}
  getText(url) {
    return this.http.get(url).map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

on the first `console.log` I have `[Object object] [Object object] [Object object]`, which is correct as I have three entries in the JSON. On the second however I've got `undefined`, which turns into an error in the browser.

```
Error in ./BodyComponent class BodyComponent - inline template:3:6 caused by: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

I'm looking at the example generated from the fountain app, but I can't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So what's in `body.html`? Also, why do you use `template: require('./body.html')` rather than `templateUrl: './body.html'`? That second `console.log` is outside the asynchronous callback, so of course `this.texts` is still undefined - either make it an empty array to start with or add handing for a missing value in the template. Also note that you're injecting `Http` in a very strange way; just write `constructor(private http: Http)` and `this.http` will be magically available in all methods.

Comment: I'm following the fountain generated app style - you can see the code here https://github.com/vladyn/rom-bg

Comment: Should that be `flatMap` instead of `map`?

Comment: Wait are you using JS or TS? Because the files say `.js` but it looks an awful lot like TS (`name: Type`, etc.). If you're new to this, I'd recommend the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for getting off the ground with tests and everything. Please put a clear [mcve] **in the question**.

Comment: It's JS - it is pointed in the question tags

Comment: JSON is never an object. JSON is always a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

- The first `console.log` is inside the callback, where `this.texts` has just been set. However the second one is *outside the callback*, so it won't have been. Therefore you'll always see `undefined` for that, because...
- ...you never set a default value for `this.texts`, and your template apparently doesn't have any e.g. `*ngIf` to handle it being `null` or `undefined`, causing errors prior to the callback being called.

Below is your code, refactored to start with an empty `this.texts` (assuming it should be an array; please adapt to taste) and simplifying the injection of `Http`. Also note the comments, and that I've used `templateUrl` to avoid the `require` and `OnInit` to trigger the HTTP call slightly later in the component lifecycle rather than doing it in the constructor.

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';  // note consistent quotes
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'body-selector',
  templateUrl: './body.html',
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {
  texts: any[] = [];  // start with an empty array

  constructor(private http: Http) { }  // inject Http here, no need to assign to this

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get('app/texts/main.json')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);  // only log *inside* the callback
        this.texts = result;
      });
    // outside the callback, the HTTP call hasn't yet finished
  }

}
```

You could also solve this by having an `ngIf` in your HTML to prevent the element from being loaded before the data is.

```html
<div class="main-container" *ngIf="texts">
  ...
</div>
```

**I'd strongly recommend running through the basic Angular 2 tutorials to get on top of this stuff, see e.g. [the Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).**

Comment: This is really good explanation! However with this code I'm still getting same error - Error: Error in ./BodyComponent class BodyComponent - inline template:3:6 caused by: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: @Vladyn don't send people offsite, put a [mcve] in the question. And please feel free not to email me; evidently you're aware you can comment here, so stick to that.

Comment: Yeah - remove it. Also updated and in the template *ngIf now avoids the error, but the template still can't receive any texts

Comment: It stated fundamentals. It handles the error. It introduced to me alternative way of initialization and yes - I should walk through basics of version2.

Answer (score 1):

You get undefined because this:

`this.getText('app/texts/main.json')`

Is an asynchronous call that gets the data and when it's done, it executes the code in the 'subscribe' block. So this.text is empty until that executes. That is the expected behavior.

Comment: How can I get the text then?

Comment: You already have it. The constructor calls the async method, when it's done, you have the text. Your problem is only that you are trying to access that in the constructor or your component.

Comment: Right, it's undefined because you never give it a null value to start with. Just define it with public texts: string = '' on top of your component.

Answer (score -1):

Better way to use data or making API call use service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

@Injectable()
export class BodyService {
  private _requestOptions: RequestOptions;

  private static handleError(error: Response): ErrorObservable {
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    this._requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
  }

  /**
   * [getJsonData will get data of json file: main.json ]
  */
  getJsonData() {
    return this.http.get('app/texts/main.json', this._requestOptions)
        .map(res => res.json())    //needs to add map for converting data in json format
        .catch(BodyService.handleError);
  }
}
```

Now Inject this service in your component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { BodyService } from './adminModules.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'body-selector',
  templateUrl: './body.html',
  providers: [BodyService]
})

export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {
texts: any = [];  // start with an empty array
errorMessage: any;

 constructor(private _bodyService: BodyService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this._bodyService.getJsonData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.texts = data;
      console.log('data', this.texts);
     }, error => {
        this.errorMessage = <any> error;
    })
  }

}
```

For calling service, you can call directly in constructor or create one method and call either in constructor or any place where you want to call.

Hope it will helpful for you :)